# How to safely check if a document exists by checking the unique phone in Firestore at client side?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If we expose the read permission because of the reason of checking the uniqueness of the document (phone field must be unique), the collections will then be accessible to the public.

How to set the rule in Firestore so that the client side can only check whether the document (by querying some attribute) exists but not exposes the collection??

Answer (score 1):

If you require unique phone number on signup event, you can create a firebase trigger function to check whether the phone number is already in document or not and respond according to that.

Additionally, in firebase rules you can give special permission to your function and by following this method you only expose your phone numbers to firebase function only.

You can use TIP#3 from [this link](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/firebase-security-rules-admin-sdk-tips.html) to achieve my logic or can get idea how to apply in your own logic, it solves your problem.

You can create a firebase function check your logic there and call that firebase function from the client side. This way you can overcome your problem.